How do I search a phrase in pdf?
I can not search a phrase in pdf in preview as the following screenshot shows, I want to search The New York Times, but apparently preview can't do that.
If I add double quotes to the phrase "The New York Times", preview then shows no result at all.

No result when I add double quotes (or single quotes) to it,

How do I search a phrase in pdf ?
